# how to create thread inside Service

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to store sensors continuous data in database using a thread inside a service.
Here's my code

My activity's code:

```
    public class TrackingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackService.class);
    startService(i);

    }
 }
```

And Service Class code:

```
    public class TrackService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;

double ax, ay, az;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);


    if (mSensor != null) {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    } else {

        stopSelf();
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        ax = event.values[0];
        ay = event.values[1];
        az = event.values[2];
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
}
```

}

As I am a newbie in Android, I don't know how to create thread in service to store Accelerometer's data continuously in database or file.

Comment: is your question about creating threads or persisting data?

Comment: Both..Actually persisting data using thread

Comment: are you sure you need a separate thread for that?

Comment: @nandsito is there any way it can be done without a separate thread? I would really like to knw

Comment: in some cases you might need it. Take a look https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html